# How does append grows up capacity with more than one elements?

Tags: go

I'm not sure how does append work, there are two case as follow:

case 1:

```
s := make([]int, 0)
s = append(s, 1)
s = append(s, 2)
s = append(s, 3)
s = append(s, 4)
s = append(s, 5)

fmt.Println(cap(s))
```

In this case output is 8 and this is make sense.

case 2:

```
s := make([]int, 0)
s = append(s, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

fmt.Println(cap(s))
```

But this case output is 6

Could anyone explain for me?

Comment: When you append a slice and the capacity grows, it is determined by whatever the language implementation thinks is best, and you shouldn't read into it too much. Basically, unless you set the capacity yourself, you shouldn't depend on it. Here's the relevant line if you want to read the nitty gritty details. Because in the second example the new size is more than double the old size, the capacity gets set to exactly the number of elements. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dec3d00b28657ce9e2fe725c858a46c3dd3fd594/src/runtime/slice.go#L146

Comment: "Could anyone explain for me?" Yes, no, it depends. There simply _is_ nothing to see or explain here. `append` must grow the underlying array if there is not enough space, but _how_ it does this or by how _much_ it grows. This is completely _unspecified_ and different compilers can do it differently. Basically it boils down to: "This is none of your business". If you know or can guess the needed cap: Create the slice with that cap via make. If you rely on append increasing the size: Let append do its job the way it works.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the capacity is rounded up a small amount before allocating for efficiency purposes, that's why you're getting a cap of 6 when you added 5 ints.  This can all be seen in the `growslice` function linked above

Comment: Btw. This is a duplicate, you might find more questions and answers like this here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

if you learn about the vector in C++,
you will know the capacity is Dynamically growing,
When you add elements, you will judge whether the capacity is enough. If not enough, the capacity will be increased(not one by one).
In 
[Where is the implementation of func append in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405327/where-is-the-implementation-of-func-append-in-go)
we can see

```
CMPQ    BX, DI                 // compare new length (2) with cap (1)
JHI $1, 225                    // jump to grow code if len > cap
```

[in offical website](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

```
func Append(slice []int, elements ...int) []int {
    n := len(slice)
    total := len(slice) + len(elements)
    if total > cap(slice) {
        // Reallocate. Grow to 1.5 times the new size, so we can still grow.
        newSize := total*3/2 + 1
        newSlice := make([]int, total, newSize)
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[:total]
    copy(slice[n:], elements)
    return slice
}

func Append(slice []int, items ...int) []int {
    for _, item := range items {
        slice = Extend(slice, item)
    }
    return slice
}
func Extend(slice []int, element int) []int {
    n := len(slice)
    if n == cap(slice) {
        // Slice is full; must grow.
        // We double its size and add 1, so if the size is zero we still grow.
        newSlice := make([]int, len(slice), 2*len(slice)+1)
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[0 : n+1]
    slice[n] = element
    return slice
}
```

newSize := total*3/2 + 1

so first uses Append: 0->1->2->4->4->8(5x3/2+1)
second uses Extend: 0->1->2->4->4->6(3*2)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to show with the patterns at the end of your post because 1. The patterns are wrong, and 2. Those functions in the blog post aren't the real code that the runtime uses to grow slices, they're just illustrative examples.